# Powered by ILNumerics

Tags: branding, ilnumerics

We are using the professional Version 3.0. In the ILPanel always the "Powered by ILNumerics" appears. Only when we are using local scenes ne wILScens(true) it disappears. Is there really a need to show this for the paid version always? I think the prama statement around this message is wrong or the HIDE_BRANDING variable has not been set correctly.

Thanks

Matthias

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
scene.Screen.First<ILLabel>().Visible = false;
```